# React Hook 'useEffect' Conditional Call Issue:

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm currently working on a Next project and have encountered an issue related to the use Effect hook and conditional rendering. Below is a snippet of the code in question:

```
const ImageGeneration: React.FC<{
  subscribedUsersData: any
  error: any; // Replace 'any' with the actual type of error if possible
}> = ({ subscribedUsersData, error }) => {
  const isDisplayEnabled = IsDisplayEnabled();

  if (error) {
    return null; // or return some appropriate JSX here
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateExpiryDate = async () => {
      // Your logic for updating expiry date goes here
    };

    updateExpiryDate();
  }, [subscribedUsersData]);

  // Rest of your component logic goes here

  return (
    // JSX for the component goes here
  );
};
```

I am specifically interested in having the if (error) statement at the top to avoid unnecessary execution of the use Effect block when an error is present. I would appreciate your insights on whether this approach is appropriate or if there are better practices for handling such scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [Drew Reese's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77837074/5157454).

It seems that the `error` property only function is to avoid rendering the JSX of `ImageGeneration` (or rendering a fallback).

It this case it's easier to avoid calling `ImageGeneration` from the parent if there's an error instead of passing the error:

```
{!error && <ImageGeneration subscribedUsersData={subscribedUsersData} />}
```

Or by rendering a fallback:

```
{error ? <div>{error}</div> : <ImageGeneration subscribedUsersData={subscribedUsersData} />}
```

Answer (score 2):

React hooks can not be conditionally called, this breaks the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

## Only Call Hooks at the Top Level

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, ***always use Hooks at the top level of your React function,
> before any early returns***. By following this rule, you ensure that
> Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
> That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
> between multiple `useState` and `useEffect` calls.

The `if (error) ...` ***MUST*** come after all hooks in the component.

If you want, you can include `error` in the dependency array and include it in some conditional call ***in*** the `useEffect` hook's callback.

Example:

```js
const ImageGeneration: React.FC<{
  subscribedUsersData: any
  error: any;
}> = ({ subscribedUsersData, error }) => {
  const isDisplayEnabled = IsDisplayEnabled();

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateExpiryDate = async () => {
      // Your logic for updating expiry date goes here
    };

    if (error) return; // <-- return early, don't run rest of effect

    updateExpiryDate();
  }, [error, subscribedUsersData]);

  if (error) {
    return null; // or return some appropriate JSX here
  }

  // Rest of your component logic goes here

  return (
    // JSX for the component goes here
  );
};
```